# How do I pass an AMPscript static variable to Send Log

Tags: html, variables, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have created a series of emails for Journey Builder. The journey is triggered by a file drop with the user data and Email_Series, which defines which initial email they should receive. A click engagement can send the user down a different path and receive different emails only on that path. We want to add a static Email_Series to those path emails to be copied to the Send Log so our custom reporting indicates if a path email was sent during the journey. We have tried using AMPscript

```ampscript
%%[

var @Email_Series

SET @Email_Series = 'wfrate1'

]%%
```

and a variety of other AMPScript codes, but we cannot get the coded Email_Series to overwrite the Email_Series being passed in from the trigger file.

TL;DR: I need to pass a static AMPscript variable to our Send Log.

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) and [ampscript](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ampscript) tags.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to match the name of the contextual variable to the column name in the Send Log.

Once you've added an appropriately sized `Email_Series` column to your send log, set the variable's value in the scripting and ensure send logging is enabled in the send definition.

Comment: Thank you! Email_Series already exists in the Send Log, we set the value, and we ensured send logging is enabled. I'm guessing we're just getting it wrong with the AMPscript to set the value, but I've tried every iteration I can think of to set that value.

Comment: I'd suggest an AMPscript block or template slot at the top of your email to supplement your send context values from your audience.  It's pretty easy to test.

Comment: Would you recommend something other than the AMPscript I used above?

Comment: That's how I generally do it.